# asp.net vb RJS PopCalendar control stopped working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datepicker

I am using a datepicker control called the RJS PoPCalendar.  It worked perfectly before, but I've been having some weird stuff happening to my visual Web Developer 2010.  Here's what I have checked:

Reference to .dll file for RJS PopCalendar is still present
verified Library2010 folder and .dll file are in my bin folder for my site
verified POPCalendar2010 folder is in site root directory
verified assembly line included at top of .aspx web form (<%@ Register assembly="RJS.Web.WebControl.PopCalendar.Net.2010" namespace="RJS.Web.WebControl" tagprefix="rjs" %>)
verified POPCalendar control is visible in toolbox

when I drag and drop the control next to a textbox control, nothing happens, nothing appears.

This used to work perfectly, what have I lost?

Comment: This is a control featured on MSDN but I can't find any assistance there...

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this myself after an hour or so struggling, so its worth it to save someone else the time.

Visual Web Developer 2010 like to forget references if you move files to new projects (I've been trying things out on individual websites and moving them into my actual project once I get them working).

To fix the problem above I had to re-reference the .dll, remove and re-add the files to my bin and root directory and remove and re-add the control to my toolbox.

Hope this helps someone save time and headache in the future!